# Query to display top product for each category in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
category  product    sale 
C1         P1        10
C2         P2        12
C3         P1        14
C1         P2        15
C1         P1        16
C2         P2        10
C2         P3        22
C3         P1        01
C3         P2        27
C3         P3        02
```

I want to group by category and get sum of sales and moreover the top product in each category. (Top product is actually the maximum occurrence of product in products, not via sales)

Expected Output:

```
category  Top product   Total sales 
    C1         P1        38
    C2         P2        44
    C3         P1        44
```

I have written the following MySQL query, but I get error (Invalid column name for products):

```
SELECT SUM(product) AS pro FROM
(SELECT category, count(sale)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `table`.`category`
) as t2
ORDER BY pro DESC LIMIT 1
```

I am struggling to write the correct MySQL query, can anyone please point out the issue?

Comment: What is your MySQL version ? and what would be your expected output, as per your given sample dataset

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get total sales per category along with top product you can use correlated/dependent sub query as

```
select t.category, 
       sum(t.sale) sales,
        (select product 
        from demo 
        where  category = t.category
        group by product
        order by count(*) desc
        limit 1) top_product
from demo t
group by t.category
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8c551/7)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. By top product, I meant the maximum number of occurrence in the column and not by sales.

Comment: @MariumMalik I have updated my answer based on your updated question, please have a look

Comment: Thank you for the help! The query works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) to get the Top product (having highest sale) in a category. Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  t.category, 
  SUM(t.sale) AS total_sales, 
  (SELECT t2.product 
   FROM `table` AS t2 
   WHERE t2.category = t.category 
   ORDER BY t2.sale DESC LIMIT 1) AS top_product 
FROM
  `table` AS t 
GROUP BY t.category
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mL9Miqp1krG6EAEy8uZLxE/0)

Comment: Top product is not a product with highest sales, it's a product that appears the most in Products category.

Comment: @MariumMalik what would be the expected output, as per your sample data in the question ?

Comment: I have added my expected output

Comment: Getting error in Fiddle when I am running your code.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL only solution, so don't use this when you need database portability in your code.

Using `GROUP_CONCAT` in combination with nested `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions to get the first element/item can also be used to get a extra column which keeping the correct grouped information..

Note: `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` is very important to use otherwise `GROUP_CONCAT` will only display 1024 bytes..

**Query**

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;

SELECT 
   Table1.category
 , SUM(Table1.sale) sum_per_category
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         GROUP_CONCAT(product ORDER BY sale DESC)
       , ','
       , 1
     )
     , ','
     , -1
   ) AS most_sold_product_in_category
FROM 
 Table1 
GROUP BY 
 Table1.category
```

**Result**

```
| category | sum_per_category | most_sold_product_in_category |
|----------|------------------|-------------------------------|
|       C1 |               26 |                            P3 |
|       C2 |               12 |                            P2 |
|       C3 |               14 |                            P1 |
|       C4 |               15 |                            P2 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eb073/13

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
SELECT t2.category, t2.sales,(select product        
                              from `table` 
                              where sale=(select max(b.sale) 
                                          from `table` b
                                          where b.category=t2.category)  limit 1)
FROM
(SELECT category, sum(sale) as sales
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `table`.`category`
) as t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select q.*,SUM(sale) from

(SELECT *
FROM `categories` order by sale desc limit 50 
) as q group by q.category
```